# Vertically and Horizontally Center an Image On Load

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment, centering

I would like to, once the document loads, center an image. Here's the catch. My document's width is greater than the browser's height, so I can't center it vertically in relation to the document. I can't center it vertically in relation to the browser height because if a user opens up the document in a browser that is not full screen, it will be positioned differently than being full screen.

Essentially, I need a way to center an image on the browser screen when full screen, even if the document is opened when not full screen.

**Update This is what I tried**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var docheight = $(window).height();
var logopositionheight = docheight/2;
var docwidth = $(window).width();
var logopositionwidth = docwidth/2;
$('#welcome_logo').css({position: 'absolute'});
$('#welcome_logo').css({top:logopositionheight-150});   
$('#welcome_logo').css({left:logopositionwidth-500});   
});
</script>
```

I also changed the $(window) to $(document) but neither worked because of what I described above.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the issue you're running into? Do you have any code that you could share? Maybe set up a jsfiddle to showcase the issue?

Comment: I updated the question to include what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Give the image a `top` and `left` of `50%` then subtract half of the image's height and width from the margin, for example if your landscape image was 200px by 100px you would write `margin: -100px 0 0 -50px`, this should center the image perfectly.

You may also need to change the `position` element depending on containers and preference to either `fixed` or `absolute`.

Comment: That's for entire document though and my document is larger than the window. I need the center of a full size window that works even when the window is not full size.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Shakesy said, you need to get your browser's "canvas" dimensions with innerHeight and innerWidth. 
Once you get that you can position the image horizontally with:
**`(( innerWidth / 2 ) - ( imageWidth / 2 ))`**.
 Also, the vertical position can be set with:
**`(( innerHeight / 2 ) - ( imageHeight / 2 ))`**.
You can put this "after" the page has loaded.

Comment: It doesn't work when the page is loaded with a browser window that it not full size. That's been my problem

Comment: Just for clarity, why is your content wider than the document.innerHeight? Should you not strive to fit your content within the document?

Comment: Not wider, taller. It is scroll intensive. I know with the whole above the fold idea but I'm making a website with some scrolling. That was not the problem though for me. It is that loading it when the browser window is not full size centers the image on that window so that when it is full size the image stays in place and is out of wack.

Answer (score 0):

First option, using JS (from user3592733's answer in part):

Javascript

```
function initialize(imageWidth, imageHeight) {
el.style.top = ""+(( innerHeight / 2 ) - ( imageHeight / 2 ))+"px";
el.style.left = ""+(( innerWidth / 2 ) - ( imageWidth / 2 ))+"px";
}
initialize();
// will update when browser is resized
window.onresize = initialize;
```

Or second option, using CSS and display:table

Main Page

```
<style type="text/css">
.wrapperdiv {
position:absolute;
display:table;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.containerdiv {
display:table-cell;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ifiedivdisplayinlineblock.css" />
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapperdiv">
<div class="containerdiv">
content here
</div>
</div>
```

ifiedivdisplayinlineblock.css

```
.wrapperdiv {
display:inline-block;
}
```

It's kind of a pain in CSS but that's how I do it on my page :) pretty self explanatory I think

Comment: The css option uses percents and from what I have seen so far, that doesn't work. I commented about the problem with innerheight and innerwidth as well.

Answer (score 0):

Re-sizing the browser is handled by the operating system, so the contents inside the browser is not "controlled" by the operating system as such but rendered by the browser itself. So, in other words, when the browser is sensing that it is being re-sized by the user it can send a trigger to javascript informing it of such an event.
 For Mozilla you can try
(1)https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize